# Where do I find my party members?

Tags: 7th-dragon-iii-code-vfd

Before initializing 7th Encount for the first time, I was told I should go find two more party members to be safe. I looked around and couldn't find anyone so I decided to just risk it, then promptly got killed by some bunnies.

Thus, I definitely need party members. Unfortunately, I *still* can't find whoever I'm supposed to find. Since this is such a niche game, there are no guides or walkthroughs. I feel like I'm supposed to easily find whoever joins my party but I haven't seen anyone that stands out at all and I've talked to literally everyone I can find in the surrounding area.

Where are my other two party members?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add party members by accessing the terminal.[The terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bCbs.jpg)